# android-Application crash when thread.start() called. App using AndroidPlot API

Tags: android, multithreading, bluetooth, uuid, android-logcat

I am building an app to plot dynamic values which are recieved via bluetooth. Since im new to android, I used the tutorial [on the android developers guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html) but the application crashes when it tries accessing the Thread.start() method. Here is the code and I could not post the LogCat since my emulator does not support Bluetooth. Here is the code.
**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.enose.sensor;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.os.MessageQueue;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.androidplot.xy.BoundaryMode;
import com.androidplot.xy.LineAndPointFormatter;
import com.androidplot.xy.LineAndPointRenderer;
import com.androidplot.xy.SimpleXYSeries;
import com.androidplot.xy.XYPlot;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStop();
        }

    private static final int HISTORY_SIZE = 30;
    public static final int MESSAGE_READ = 0;
    private XYPlot aprHistoryPlot = null;
    private SimpleXYSeries alcohol=null;
    private SimpleXYSeries lpg=null;
    private SimpleXYSeries methane=null;
    private SimpleXYSeries quality=null;
    private LinkedList<Number> alcoholHistory;
    private LinkedList<Number> lpgHistory;
    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    //private UUID uid;
    //Thread to initiate connection
    private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;
        public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
            // Use a temporary object that is later assigned to mmSocket,
            // because mmSocket is final
            BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
            mmDevice = device;

            // Get a BluetoothSocket to connect with the given BluetoothDevice
            try {

                tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID.fromString("0000110100001000800000805F9B34FB"));
            } catch (IOException e) { }
            mmSocket = tmp;
        }

        public void run() {
            // Cancel discovery because it will slow down the connection
            mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

            try {
                // Connect the device through the socket. This will block
                // until it succeeds or throws an exception
                mmSocket.connect();
            } catch (IOException connectException) {
                // Unable to connect; close the socket and get out
                try {
                    mmSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException closeException) { }
                return;
            }

            // Do work to manage the connection (in a separate thread)
            //manageConnectedSocket(mmSocket);
        }
        public void manageConnectedSocket(BluetoothSocket socket)
        {
            ConnectedThread data=new ConnectedThread(socket);
            data.start();
        }
        /** Will cancel an in-progress connection, and close the socket */
        public void cancel() {
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) { }
        }
    }
    public class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final InputStream mmInStream;
        private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
            mmSocket = socket;
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;

            // Get the input and output streams, using temp objects because
            // member streams are final
            try {
                tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
                tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) { }

            mmInStream = tmpIn;
            mmOutStream = tmpOut;
        }

        public void run() {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];  // buffer store for the stream
            int bytes; // bytes returned from read()
            // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
            while (true) {
                try {
                    // Read from the InputStream
                    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                    // Send the obtained bytes to the UI activity
                //    h.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_READ,bytes,-1,buffer)
                  //          .sendToTarget();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        /* Call this from the main activity to send data to the remote device */
        public void write(byte[] bytes) {
            try {
                mmOutStream.write(bytes);
            } catch (IOException e) { }
        }

        /* Call this from the main activity to shutdown the connection */
        public void cancel() {
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) { }
        }
    }
    private LinkedList<Number> methaneHistory;
    {
        alcoholHistory = new LinkedList<Number>();
        lpgHistory = new LinkedList<Number>();
        methaneHistory = new LinkedList<Number>();

        alcohol = new SimpleXYSeries("Alcohol");
        lpg = new SimpleXYSeries("LPG");
        methane = new SimpleXYSeries("Methane");
        quality = new SimpleXYSeries("Air Quality");
    }
    private class MyHandler extends Handler
    {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.handleMessage(msg);
            int val=msg.arg1;
            byte[] d=(byte[]) msg.obj;
            Double s1;
            s1=Double.longBitsToDouble(val);
            alcoholHistory.addLast(s1);
            if(alcoholHistory.size()>30)
                alcoholHistory.removeFirst();
            alcohol.setModel(alcoholHistory,SimpleXYSeries.ArrayFormat.Y_VALS_ONLY);
            aprHistoryPlot.redraw();
        }

    }
    //MyHandler h;
    private BluetoothDevice selDevice;
    private Context context;
    private BluetoothSocket tmp;
    private ConnectThread connect;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Handler h=new Handler();
        context=this;
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        aprHistoryPlot = (XYPlot) findViewById(R.id.aprHistoryPlot);
        alcoholHistory.addFirst(2);
        lpgHistory.addFirst(3);
        methaneHistory.addFirst(4);
        alcoholHistory.addFirst(3);
        lpgHistory.addFirst(2);
        methaneHistory.addFirst(1);

        alcohol.setModel(alcoholHistory, SimpleXYSeries.ArrayFormat.Y_VALS_ONLY);
        lpg.setModel(lpgHistory, SimpleXYSeries.ArrayFormat.Y_VALS_ONLY);
        methane.setModel(methaneHistory, SimpleXYSeries.ArrayFormat.Y_VALS_ONLY);
        aprHistoryPlot.setRangeBoundaries(0, 5,BoundaryMode.FIXED);
        aprHistoryPlot.setDomainBoundaries(0, 30, BoundaryMode.FIXED);
        aprHistoryPlot.addSeries(alcohol, LineAndPointRenderer.class, new LineAndPointFormatter(Color.rgb(0, 100, 200), Color.BLACK,null));
        aprHistoryPlot.addSeries(lpg, LineAndPointRenderer.class, new LineAndPointFormatter(Color.rgb(100, 200, 100), Color.BLACK,null));
        aprHistoryPlot.addSeries(methane, LineAndPointRenderer.class, new LineAndPointFormatter(Color.rgb(200, 100, 100), Color.BLACK,null));
        aprHistoryPlot.setDomainStepValue(1);
        aprHistoryPlot.setTicksPerRangeLabel(3);
        aprHistoryPlot.setDomainLabel("time");
        aprHistoryPlot.getDomainLabelWidget().pack();
        aprHistoryPlot.setRangeLabel("level");
        aprHistoryPlot.getRangeLabelWidget().pack();
        aprHistoryPlot.disableAllMarkup();
        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
            // Device does not support Bluetooth
            Toast.makeText(context, "Not supported", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else{
            //Toast.makeText(context, "test1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            mBluetoothAdapter.enable();
         // Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
         //   startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
        }
        Toast.makeText(context, "test2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Set<BluetoothDevice> devices=mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
        boolean isDeviceSet=false;
        if(devices==null)
        {
            Toast.makeText(context, "No paired devices", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
        else
        {
            //Toast.makeText(context, "test3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //BluetoothDevice dev=mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice("006645ffly477");
            for (BluetoothDevice device : devices) {
                // Add the name and address to an array adapter to show in a ListView
                //mArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
                selDevice=device;
                isDeviceSet=true;
                //TextView tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtlist);
                //tv.setText("Bluetooth device "+selDevice.getName()+" selected");
                break;
                }
        Message msg=h.obtainMessage();
        //uid=new UUID(7659464,976328762);
        //Toast.makeText(context, "test4", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT   ).show();
            //connect=new ConnectThread(dev);
            //connect.run();
            //dev=mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice("006645ffly477");
            //if(dev!=null)
                //Toast.makeText(context, "device null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //else

        //connect=new ConnectThread(selDevice);
          //    connect.run();
            }
        }
        }
    }
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.enose.sensor"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="5"
        android:targetSdkVersion="10" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <com.androidplot.xy.XYPlot
    android:id="@+id/aprHistoryPlot"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10px"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10px"
    android:layout_marginRight="10px"
    title="eNose Readings"/>
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/txtlist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Logcat**

```
10-04 16:09:01.508: E/InputDispatcher(62): channel '4074d648 com.example.enose.sensor/com.example.enose.sensor.MainActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
10-04 16:09:01.508: E/InputDispatcher(62): channel '4074d648 com.example.enose.sensor/com.example.enose.sensor.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
10-04 16:12:09.808: E/InputDispatcher(62): channel '405ecbb8 com.example.enose.sensor/com.example.enose.sensor.MainActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
10-04 16:12:09.808: E/InputDispatcher(62): channel '405ecbb8 com.example.enose.sensor/com.example.enose.sensor.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
10-04 21:11:42.588: E/InputDispatcher(62): channel '405a9a88 com.example.enose.sensor/com.example.enose.sensor.MainActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
10-04 21:11:42.588: E/InputDispatcher(62): channel '405a9a88 com.example.enose.sensor/com.example.enose.sensor.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
10-04 21:11:57.488: E/InputDispatcher(62): channel '40746548 com.example.enose.sensor/com.example.enose.sensor.MainActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
10-04 21:11:57.488: E/InputDispatcher(62): channel '40746548 com.example.enose.sensor/com.example.enose.sensor.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
10-04 21:39:31.018: E/InputDispatcher(62): channel '4061f108 com.example.enose.sensor/com.example.enose.sensor.MainActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
10-04 21:39:31.018: E/InputDispatcher(62): channel '4061f108 com.example.enose.sensor/com.example.enose.sensor.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
```

If this cannot work. Can someone post an easy tutorial on connecting via bluetooth to a device with a known MAC address?
And also can someone explain the process of getting a UUID and its use?

Comment: could you post the logcat,it would be easy to help you out .

Comment: I am not able to debug the program on the emulator as it does not support bluetooth. Can you suggest a workaround so that I can get the logcat?

Comment: just connect your device to the system, eclipse will detect it. run your program and you will be able to see the DDMS Logcat.

Comment: Yes i got it. check the edits

Comment: its not clear from the portion of logcat you have posted that what exactly is the error, so do one thing use Log.d() at every step , and see which is the exact step its giving you an error from the logcat itself.

Comment: Yes. I found out where my mistake is. Its in the code, device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID.fromString("0000110100001000800000805F9B34FB")). Can you sort it out?

Answer (score 0):

try adding this permission also in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not able to use Bluetooth in the Emulator, so it will crash. You need a real  Bluetooth device to test it.